# How to set domain for web resources in an Iframe

Tags: css, web, flask, airflow

I am currently working on integrating apache airflow (flask application) with an authentication service as a micro-app. The authentication service loads the airflow in an Iframe. I am able to load the landing page of airflow in an Iframe of the authentication service ui.

The landing page in turn contains css and other external resources. How can I force them to be loaded from a specific location. I currently have the airflow landing page that renders html containing css dependencies like this.

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

which in turn makes the request like this `authentictaion_domain.com/static/bootstrap-theme.css`

What I want is the resources to get loaded through the Authetication service domain like this 
`authentictaion_domain.com/my-microapp/static/bootstrap-theme.css`

Is there any way I can get this to work without making significant changes to all the paths in airflow ui.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a flask expert, but I imagine it should just be a matter of updating the `static_folder` path when airflow initializes the flask app.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/app.py#L73

The path for the static assets is generated with flasks `url_for()` function

That being said, I do want to ask, does your authentication service reverse proxy the airflow webserver?  Or is it just a protected UI with an iframe?  If it is the latter, then it's not really securing airflow. If someone stumbles upon the airflow webserver URL they'd still be able to access it outside of the iframe.

I do want to mention that airflow does [supports different methods of authentication.](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#roll-your-own)  So if you have your own user system for your main site, you can write a backend to authenticate against that database for access to airflow, and set your airflow.cfg to use that backend.

At [Astronomer](https://astronomer.io), where I work, I wrote [a custom backend](https://github.com/astronomerio/incubator-airflow/blob/astronomer-fixes-182/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/astronomer_auth.py) for our fork of airflow we use in our SaaS platform.  When airflow prompts to login, it will make authentication requests against our API. If valid, it will create a flask user in airflow with a matching email address and log the user into it.